# How can I change the scale of one series in a Google Sheets chart?

Tags: google-sheets, charts

I'm trying to put together a combo chart that will use time values for the x-axis as well as the line series and combine that with integer values for the bar chart portion.

The problem is that because my times are between 00:02:00 and 01:30:00, the bar graph's values of 1-15 dwarf the time values.

Is there a way to display the bar chart with a separate scale so 4 and 00:04:00 look reasonably close?

Comment: did you try the option: "treat labels as text" ?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately. I think the problem is that according to Sheets 00:01:00 = 0.01. If I change the integer values to 0.0X it looks about right but that's a bit hackier than I'd like

Comment: Does that mean that you made it work? Could you post a sample sheet and an answer?